# Cloud function creation on GCP fails with Terraform

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, deployment, terraform, google-cloud-functions

friends! I'm pretty new on deploying golang applications to GCP. So when I try to deploy my golang app on cloud function with terraform it fails.

This is my main.tf:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket" {
  name     = "some-bucket"
  location = "US"
  project  = "some-project"
  uniform_bucket_level_access = true
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "archive" {
  name   = "function.zip"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
  source = "C:/Users/User/Downloads/function.zip"
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function" {
  name        = "some-name"
  description = "some-description"
  runtime     = "go119"
  project     = "some-project"
  region      = "us-central1"

  available_memory_mb = 128

  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.archive.name
  entry_point           = "main"
  trigger_http          = true
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_member" "invoker" {
  project        = google_cloudfunctions_function.function.project
  region         = google_cloudfunctions_function.function.region
  cloud_function = google_cloudfunctions_function.function.name

  role   = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
  member = "allUsers"
}
```

But when running `terraform apply` I'm facing this issue:
Error: Error waiting for Creating CloudFunctions Function: Error code 3, message: Build failed: functions.local/app/main.go:18:2: import "example.com/gcp-cost-lambda" is a program, not an importable package; Error ID: 6fba28bd

This is my project structure:
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbBd7.png)
This is my main.go imports section:
package main

```
import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "example.com/gcp-cost-lambda/cost"
    "example.com/gcp-cost-lambda/notification/email"
    "example.com/gcp-cost-lambda/notification/slack"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)
```

And this is a beginning of my go.mod:

```
module example.com/gcp-cost-lambda
go 1.19
```

The app itself builds and runs with no problems locally on my PC, but cloud function is not working at all. I would be insanely grateful for any help!

Comment: Are you able to deploy the code to GCP *without* using Terraform? That's the first thing I'd try - separate out the Terraform aspect from the function aspect.

Comment: Did you try a go mod tidy?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I've tried to deploy it manually. Still fails with same error

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, I run go mod tidy several times

Comment: Right, in that case I would suggest getting rid of everything about Terraform from the question. Focus on deploying it manually, and once that's done, hopefully it'll be fine in Terraform.